# What is the safest way to cast a given value to enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums, casting

I want to check if a given value belongs to MyEnum, which type is uint8. The given value could be uint8 or not, e.g., it could also be int, uint16, etc.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum class MyEnum : std::uint8_t
    {
        A = 0,
        B = 1,
        C = 2,
        D = 3,
    };

    int x = 256;  // Note that this is not uint8
    switch(MyEnum(x))
    {
    case MyEnum::A:
    case MyEnum::B:
    case MyEnum::C:
    case MyEnum::D:
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "NOT OK" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
OK
```

As you can see, 256 is casted to uint8_t 0, which is MyEnum::A.

**My Question**

What is the standard way in C++ to check if a given value belongs to an enum? Given the example above, is there any other way than just checking the value explicitly before casting?

```
if (x < 0 || x > 255)
{
    // Do not cast to MyEnum
};
else
{
    // Cast to MyEnum
}
```

Comment: The value `256` doesn't even fit in an `uint8_t`.

Comment: do you want to check if the value is in the range of `uint8_t` or if the value has a enumerator? enums have much more valid values than enumerators typically

Comment: `256` cast to `uint8_t` is `0` which is `MyEnum::A`

Comment: You should at least add something like `if (x > std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) { std::cout << "not ok";} else { /* your switch, here */ }`, when `x` has a type wider than the underlying type of the enum.

Comment: define "safe". Protect from integer overflow? must match some enum value?

Comment: By safe I meant: protecting from overflow plus not assigning the value to undesired MyEnum. Of course the value "x" can be checked beforehand, as it was commented above, but would that be the common practice in C++?

Comment: Enums might be stranger then you think : [So you thought C++ was weird, meet enums](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGfk5l85cko&t=168s). Light hearted video that still may teach you a thing or two :) And will allow you to better phrase what you  mean by "safe"

Comment: Ok please [edit] your question so other do not have to go though comments. Also add information what you are expecting to happen when value is wrong.

Comment: I want to be able to define `enum class MyEnum { MyEnum(int x) { assert(x < 0 || x > 3); } A, B, C, D };`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yeah, but scoped enums aren't really classes, so you either write one or use a conversion function.

Comment: `MyEnum to_MyEnum(int x) { if (x < 0 || x > 3) throw std::logic_error("to_MyEnum"); return static_cast<MyEnum>(x); }`

Comment: @Eljay That requires the user manually calling it. The benefit of a constructor would be that you can't avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to check `std::numeric_limits<underlying_type_t<MyEnum>>::max()`, which will be 255 for your `std::uint8_t`.

As for checking whether it matches one of the *named* values, this isn't possible. You cannot enumerate over names.

Note that even without an underlying type, any bitwise combination of enumerators is also valid, as is 0. Easiest to explain with an example: if you have `{READ=1, WRITE=2, EXECUTE=4}` then `1|2|4==7` is also in range.